# Data Table does not work from second page

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using a data table and I have an Action column where there are three buttons. Edit, Delete and Change Status. There is another column called Status. Now, when I click on delete button, the status will be changed to inactive and only change status button should be displayed and other two should be hidden and when the status is again changed to active the delete and edit button should be displayed and the Change Status button should be hidden. For the fist page everything works as per expectation but when I click on next page it does not work.

```
$(".tabfunction > tbody  > tr").each(function() {
  var status = $(this).find("#status").val();
  switch (status) {
    case 'Active':
      $(this).find(".stausfunction").hide();
      break;
    case 'InActive':
      $(this).find(".deletefunction").hide();
      $(this).find(".editfunction").hide();
      break;
  }
});
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  async: true
});
};
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve. Can you post your table structure so we can understand better? Also, it's generally not a good idea to modify data in the datatables with jquery. You should use the [column api](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible()) and the [filter api](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()) that the datatables offer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO - please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].  You may also find this useful: [mcve].

Comment: "*it does not work*" - the question is: when do you run the code you've provided?   It looks like it would be within `document.ready` - ie once at startup.  You need to hook into the datatables refresh/redraw event, or, better, hook into the individual row/cell render events.

Comment: I may suspect it is an event delegation issue (you're trying to attach above code to the buttons that do not yet exist within your DOM).

Comment: @user11299053 yes, that's very likely if the code is run on a button rather than once at startup

Comment: Have a look at [`rows().every()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every())

Comment: @user11299053. How do I resolve this issue. You are correct. I do understand that only the first page will exist in the DOM for datatable but how do I apply the Jquery for the entire table.

Comment: @freedomn-m  I have created a function ActionControlsVisibility() inside which I have written the above given code and I am calling this function from another function which is BindTable().

Comment: Thank you guys for all your valuable suggestions. The issue is resolved and everything is working fine now. I was doing mistake in calling the method. The order of calling was not appropriate.  I had to call the function ActionControlsVisibility() before  $(".tabchecklist").DataTable get executed.